# ColdFusion autosuggest in text field is not responsive

Tags: coldfusion

I have a text field that I want to autosuggest values based on a query. I have a main file along with a separate file (getdata.cfc) that holds my query.

Here is the text field portion of my main file:

```
<cfinput name="search_query" autosuggest="url:getdata.cfc?suggestvalue={cfautosuggestvalue}" maxResultsDisplay="10" showAutoSuggestLoadingIcon="true" size="10" />
```

Here is the code in getdata.cfc:

```
   <cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="get_data" access="remote"  output="false">
        <cfargument name="suggestvalue" required="true">

        <cfquery name="get_data" datasource="#application.DSN#">
                SELECT DISTINCT myItem 
                FROM myTable
                WHERE myItem LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#suggestvalue#%"
                cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                ORDER BY myItem 
        </cfquery>

        <cfif get_data.recordCount eq 1>
            <cfreturn ",#get_data.myItem#">
       <cfelse>
            <cfreturn ValueList(get_data.myItem)>
       </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The text field shows up fine, but when I type a word no autosuggest values show up. Nothing happens. The text is just displayed as I type it.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What's the output of something like Firebug display when you're hitting the cfc?

Comment: I have Fiddler, and it doesn't pick up that the cfc file is being hit at all.

Comment: All the docs are showing cfc for autosuggest, not url:. So it'd be: autosuggest="cfc:getdata.get_data({cfautosuggestvalue})"> They're also returning an array instead of a list.

Comment: I tried that, and both files are in the same directory, but I'm getting the error message: Problem retrieving data:The specified CFC getdata.get_data could not be found.

Comment: I am no longer receiving that error so I assume it knows where to find the file now that I have included the path. However, it still doesn't seem to be hitting the file in Fiddler.

Comment: Here are a few suggestions.... you dont have a returntype on your function:  try returntype="array"

you can always add a <cfdump var="#get_data#">.  Then go to chrome or firefix, open your page, then inspect the element.  Go to the network tab, and then right click on the cfc file and open it in a new tab to see what your function is outputting.  I find that is the best way to troubleshoot a remote function returning data.

Answer (score 2):

I switched away to using jquery plugins from a lot of CF stuff, but here is an example I have that works in some old production code

```
<cfinput type="text" name="email" id="email" autosuggest="cfc:cfc.users.lookupEmail({cfautosuggestvalue})" maxresultsdisplayed = "25">

<cffunction name="lookupEmail" access="remote" returntype="array">
    <cfargument name="search" type="any" required="false" default="">

    <!--- Define variables --->
    <cfset var data="">
    <cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>

    <!--- Do search --->
    <cfquery name="data"  datasource="datasource" maxrows="25" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#">
    SELECT distinct email
    FROM users
    WHERE email LIKE  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.search#%">
    ORDER BY email
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Build result array --->
    <cfloop query="data">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(result, email)>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- And return it --->
    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

maybe this helps

also make sure you have your cfform tags around your form, and make sure that your /cfide folder is mapped to your website.

looking at your code and comparing it... it may be the way your calling the cfc (filename)

try: autosuggest="cfc:getdata.get_data.({cfautosuggestvalue})"

Comment: I'm not sure that will help because I don't think my cfc file is being accessed at all. Thanks though. Let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: i just updated the code....autosuggest="cfc:getdata.get_data.({cfautosuggestvalue})" you were using URL:filename .... but not calling the function... so you werent getting the function firing returning your info...

Comment: if you wanted to, just add method=get_data to the string, like below, and it should work too... I prefer the cfc method.

URL:getdata.cfc?method=get_data&suggestvalue={cfautosuggestvalue}

Comment: I am getting the error: 
Problem retrieving data:The specified CFC getdata.get_data could not be found.

Comment: you probably have to update your folder path...

CFC:subfolder.subfolder.getdata.get_data({cfautosuggestvalue})

Comment: Both the files are in the same directory - do you still think I have to do that?

Comment: if your using the cfc: yes... it starts at the root directory of the site.

Comment: Steve is right; if you wanted to call it via URL, you have to point at your site's URL; using cfc is easier but you have to call the file path from the root directory of your site instead of the file itself like a cfinclude.  Just another one of CF's inconsistencies with file handling.

Comment: I tried calling it using the URL with full file path, but it still doesn't seem to do any thinking when I type in the box. Hm. I have been using Fiddler to see if it tries to hit the cfc file.

Comment: Now I am using cfc: to access the file, but it still won't hit it. Very strange.